# Routing Error - uninitialized constant UsersController? omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have this app that uses omniauth-facebook to autenticate users, a new user creates in the sessionscontroller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
  end
end
```

then it hits the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth) 
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"] unless auth["info"].blank?
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my usercontroller I have something like this to display a user profil:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And in the show.html.erb I have something like this:

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

But I get the following error: `Routing Error - uninitialized constant UsersController`

My routes file:

```
Bummerang::Application.routes.draw do


    resources :users, :only => :show

    root to: 'static_pages#home'

    match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
    match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

    # autentications routes
    match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
    match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
    match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell what the problem here is: in the future, consider posting the entire error message and the code that the error message references as being bad.

Nevertheless, my guess is: your `UsersController` is named `UserController`. It should be pluralized. Change the name to `UsersController` and this should work.

Comment: That was the problem, actually I the hole error is: Routing Error - uninitialized constant UsersController - try running rake routes.

Comment: Note that `user` in the filename also needs to be pluralized: `users_controller.rb`.

Comment: Needed to use Veraticus' and Dennis' answers to solve this for me. Other than that, I also had to change the name of the view directory (from 'user' to 'users').